# Dismissing modalView

Tags: ios6

i came across of an issue with dismissmodalview. it is apparently depreciated in ios 6. can anyone suggest a fix. i tried this code but still brings up the warning.

```
if ([[self parentViewController] respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)]){

    [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

} else {

    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

can anyone suggest anything. basically i am trying to dismiss the modal view which i am using in my view controller.

adrian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried? I'm using this in one of my projects with success.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: thanks andy. that was it. i guess i was forgetting that the modalviewcontroller is actually a view controller. thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You receive a warning because the selector is deprecated in iOS 6 and you use it. If you are targeting iOS 5 and above, you should not be using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`.

If you really need to use it, you can call `performSelector:` like so:

```
if ([[self parentViewController] respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)]){  
    [[self parentViewController] performSelector:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) withObject:@YES];
}
```

A word of advice: it is not considered good practice for a view to close itself. You should create a delegate protocol for your modal view controller, and have the presenting view controller by the modal's delegate.

Comment: thanks leo. i'll take a look at the delegate suggestion. i am working with this code in order to upgrade one of my apps, but if this does not work, i guess i have to overhaul the code and rewrite it. thanks again leo.